# Convert xls to csv

Tags: .net, excel

i need to create at runtime a csv from a xls file, i utilize this:

```
ws.SaveAs(filename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

this code work but my problem is that i need semicolon like column separator and not comma.

How can i change this behavior?

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileHelpers library to import/export data from fixed length or delimited records. This has helped me a lot in the past while dealing with csv. You can download it and also find a lot of quick start examples and sample projects [here](http://www.filehelpers.com/)

Comment: Thank you Pavanred, i'll try this library.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good library but i don't need a typed csvengine, it require:

```
 FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(SampleType));
```

but i have not SampleType...